# Remove duplicates in comboBox

Tags: c#

I have to remove duplicates in a combobox.

```
private void cbnama_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string>[] list;
    list = mDatabase.Viewpengujian();

    cbnama.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)
    {
            cbnama.Items.Add(list[0][i]);
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
test1
test2
test2
test3
test3
```

Comment: are you pulling this from a database, then it would be good to have the distinct pulled out from there

Answer (score 5):

*Updated*: Didn't notice you had a multidimensional list. @ntziolis is the first one to catch that and his answer is the right one.

If you're using C# 3.0 or later you could do:

```
list = list.SelectMany(i => i).Distinct().ToList();
```

Make sure you have `using System.Linq` on the top.

Comment: This will not compile because Distinct will return an IEnumerable<>, you have to cast: list.Distinct().ToList()

Comment: just realized that he uses multiple dimensions on the list so just calling `Distinct`is not working here, he needs to `SelectMany` before that, see my answer

Comment: can you please give an example

Comment: @gideon This is still wrong, `SelectMany` needs to be the first thing that si called, you need to flatten the multiple dimensions before calling distinct, just updated your answer + he needs to change the rest of his code as well now, since this wont compile + the for loop

Comment: Ah damn! that was so daft of me @ntziolis

Answer (score 2):

u need to check item already added or not as below , shich skip the item which is already added in combo box

```
for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)    
{                 

    if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(list[0][i]) )
    {  
       cbnama.Items.Add(list[0][i]);     
     }
}
```

Comment: one should avoid using UI elements for checking something like this, usually there is a significant overhead when using a UI element rather than a lightweight data structure like an array, also it is not separating code and UI properly

Answer (score 2):

In general this can be solved by using the `Distinct` extension method of the IEnumerable, see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx

But since you are using a multi dimensional list/array thing you need to `SelectMany` to flatten your dimensions before you can call `Distinct`, this also changes the rest of your code slightly so here is the hole method:

```
private void cbnama_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this will give you an IEnumerable<string>
    var list = mDatabase.Viewpengujian()
        .SelectMany(i => i)
        .Distinct();

    cbnama.Items.Clear();

    // since now list is a IEnumerable<string> you can just loop through it
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        cbnama.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check this example....and manipulate it as per u r need...

```
For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.Items.Count - 2
     For j As Int16 = Me.ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
          If Me.ComboBox1.Items(i).ToString = Me.ComboBox1.Items(j).ToString Then
               Me.ComboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(j)
          End If
     Next
Next
```